# Magnetisation with and without a complete magnetic flux path

Tags: electromagnetism

If I place a material in a magnetic circuit, is there a big difference in the magnetisation depending on whether the flux path closed, no air gaps with the material and magnetic source, or open, an air gap between material and the source?

I am aware that the closed circuit with produce a more uniform magnetisation, and the open circuit will have flux leakage and be less uniform with a reduction in magnetisation at the ends of the material. 
But will the magnetisation of the material be more or less the same for a given applied external field for both cases?

[image]

Comment: Can you give a sketch? The answer will strongly depend on geometry and your personal understanding of *more or less the same*.

Comment: Hi, thank you for responding to my question. I have added a sketch of the closed path, the material to be magnetised in in contact with the iron core. For the open path the, it would not be in contact with the core or the set up would be the material in a Helmholtz coil set up to create the magnetic field.

Comment: In general in the field strength is the same, the magnetization will be the roughly the same.However, the amount of current you will need to achieve the same field strength will be different for different configurations. Maybe the concept of [magnetic reluctance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_reluctance) will clarify the situation for you.

Comment: In the setup you show, I'd say that a small air gap will not make much of a difference. Changing from an iron yoke setup to an air coil Helmholtz version, will be quite a change, though.

Comment: Thank you Crimson, that does help me understand the situation better. Less current is needed for the coils to created the same field in a closed magnetic path than one with an air gap. And as a result if my material is part of a closed magnetic circuit less current is needed for the coil than if there is an air gap, where it will need to overcome some resistance caused by the air to produce the equivalent magnetic field in air.

Answer (score 0):

Magnetic turbulence causes the losses, the lines take realtime longer than no turbulence like being in contact during the process, this is likely the main concern in any magnetic circuit.